# Swing- Add text between two textual points in JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

Well, I decided to edit everything. So, the code goes like this:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (!uiCreator.getTextArea().getText().equalsIgnoreCase("Beggining text")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You must have main method first", "Error",
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        } else {
            n = Integer.valueOf(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("..."));
            l = Integer.valueOf(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("..."));
            uiCreator.getTextArea()
                    .setText("Beggining text with few additions");
```

On the code above, I made it to check if `JTextArea` contains text that is needed and if it doesn't it will show an error message. If it does it will set a text with few more words.

Now. I also have more `JButton`s. So if one is clicked, it will also do the same thing. Check the text and if it meets all conditions, set new modified text. But, now, my problem comes here. I have this:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (!uiCreator.getTextArea().getText()
                .equalsIgnoreCase("Beggining text with few additions")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error, you don't have main or JFrame inside main", "Error",
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

        } else {
            uiCreator.getTextArea()
                    .setText("Beggining text with even more additions");
        }
```

Which checks if `JTextArea` had "Beggining text with few additions" and if it did, change the text to Beggining text with even more additions. I have few more buttons that do the same thing. Now, I would like to know a way to let `setText(some text)` method be used regardless is there Beggining text with few additions or Beggining text with even more additions.

Comment: Simply modify the `text` property. `String text = textArea.getText(); ... textArea.setText(text);`

Comment: Yeah, I could do that. But the problem is that I have multiple buttons that add diffrent text. So I don't want to check was each clicked.

Comment: Your comment above doesn't explain your problem to us. What do buttons have to do with adding text? Please clarify the issue for us, and perhaps show more code. A [mcve] would help greatly.

Comment: I'm wondering if you're using the wrong component, that perhaps a JList is what you really need to use -- but don't know for sure til you tell us more.

Comment: Also consider [`MessageFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html).

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I have edited the question, hope that it's clearel now.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use setText(...) to keep replacing all the text.

Instead you can use methods like:

```
replaceSelection(...);

getDocument().insertString(...);
```

to change part of the text or insert new text.